# notice on Date and time setting change

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

In an iOS app, is there any method to get notified either user changed the date or time setting.

Actually in an app we want to know the time difference between the two app sessions. It can be done by saving the time when user closed the app and when user restart again. But what if user change the time setting in between.
Can we get noticed at the starting of the game whether user changed the time/date setting.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` is what you're looking for. But there's another case where date may change, for example when user changes time zone. In this case you need to observe `NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification is working when app is running in background and we do some changes. But it doesn't work when app is closed and we change time.

Comment: You'll receive this notification after your application will restore from background state.

Comment: yes, thats right but is there any way to get notified when app is not alive, not even in background.

Comment: You can't get any notifications when your app is not running. Even if there's a push notification it is not guaranteed that user will respond to it and launch your app. But you can read about multitasking enhancements in iOS 7 and maybe you'll figure out some workarounds to solve your problem — https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW10

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what `applicationSignificantTimeChange:` (on the app delegate) and the `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` notification is used for (though the case where the user manually changes their time is not listed as an example)